# Is it ok to use Derived Class In a Base Class Function

Tags: java

The code I saw today where I saw this function

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>{ 
    public static <T> BaseClass<T> of(T obj) {
       return new DerivedClass<T>(check(obj));
    }
}
```

Isn't this is like tying the implementation to the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If, for example `BaseClass` is part of a `public interface` and `DerivedClass` is an internal implementation, than, only the `BaseClass` is visible to an user, however not an implementation. So you just offer your implementation of `BaseClass`. But you have to show us the whole context to give you a exact answer.

Comment: I was thinking that should even this DerivedClass be injected through spring or using factory. But looks like that would be over engineering.